# Prevent Advantage Database Server from displaying/retrieving active queries

Tags: advantage-database-server

I'm using Advantage Database Server 10. The stored procedure sp_GetSQLStatements can be used to return information about all active queries including SQL statements. The same information can be viewed in Advantage Data Architect by selecting option Remote Server Info from the Tools menu on tab "Active Queries". (The Advantage Data Architect is using stored procedure sp_GetSQLStatements as well).

Is there any way to keep the server from displaying/retrieving SQL statements in order to protect my development work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data dictionary with appropriate security settings, so no one can login without proper authentication.

Comment: My VB.NET application is already using a connection through a data dictionary with authentication. But SQL commands issued by the application are shown in Data Architect on tab "Active Queries".

Answer (score 0):

I found at least a partial solution for selecting data. Using a data dictionary I create a view from the SQL statement I want to issue (and hide). Further, I create a stored procedure including only a single SQL statement of the form

```
SELECT * FROM ViewName ORDER BY someColumns;
```

This statement allows sorting (ORDER BY is not allowed in Views) and it is the only one that will be displayed by the server under "Active Queries". The "sourcecode" of the view will not be shown.

Using this workaround it is also possible to create new tables from complex views in a performant (server-side) way:

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM ViewName;
```

Other users will only see the SELECT statement of the stored procedure but not the view. It is obvious, that for UDATE and INSERT statements more code will be disclosed.